# javascript app won't access a USB device?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, linux-kernel, udev

When I launch a very light nodejs app (https://github.com/Jeija/mansonnode)* with

```
$ node server.js /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I get complains :

```
/dev/ttyUSB0 could not be opened, exiting.
Make sure you have the permission to open the port and that it exists.
```

*(I had to modify 2 or 3 lines of hcs.js in order for it to be compatible with the syntax updates of the nodejs version provided in ubuntu 20.04 repositories)

**Would you guys have an idea how to get it reaching the USB device please? Regards**

---

edit1

This https://github.com/esp8266/source-code-examples/issues/26#issuecomment-719459204 didn't work neither, and :

> `$ groups $USER`

```
user : adm tty dialout
```

Does the app is a standalone user itself that I should add to the groups `tty` and `dialout` ? I know nothing about JS/node.

The only physical peripherals plugged into the laptop are a wireless mice dongle and the manson HCS USB-A cable.

---

edit2

most recent devices plugged since 2min ago :

> `$ find /dev/bus/usb/ ! -type d -mmin -2`

```
/dev/bus/usb/001/012
```

> `$ udevadm info /dev/bus/usb/001/012`

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
N: bus/usb/001/012
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/012
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: PRODUCT=
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: BUSNUM=001
E: DEVNUM=012
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=11
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=
E: ID_VENDOR=Silicon_Labs
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Silicon\x20Labs
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=10c4
E: ID_MODEL=CP2102_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=CP2102\x20USB\x20to\x20UART\x20Bridge\x20Controller
E: ID_MODEL_ID=
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=Silicon_Labs_CP2102_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0001
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Silicon Labs
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=CP210x UART Bridge
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2
E: ID_MM_TTY_MANUAL_SCAN_ONLY=1
```

---

edit0 for @user3840170 :

```
$ id
```

gives:

```
uid=1000(me) gid=1000(me) groups=1000(me),4(adm),5(tty),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),121(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare)
```

and

```
$ getfacl /dev/ttyUSB0
```

(no matter whether the USB device is powered ON or not) gives, when plugged to the laptop USB port :

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/ttyUSB0
# owner: root
# group: dialout
user::rw-
user:me:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

Comment: Give the output of `id` and `getfacl /dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: thank you for caring, it's in the edit

Comment: Are you sure `server.js` doesn't drop priviledges?

Comment: not sure at all, even skeptical, is there a way to figure out if it is the case please?

Comment: [this is a comment for upping the thread]